# Is assigning a struct with char array directly safe?

Tags: c

I have  a struct:

```
struct test {
  int a;
  char b[20];
};

struct test x;
struct test *y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
y->a = 3;
memcpy(y->b, "aaaa", 4);
```

then if I assign `x = *y`;

and `free(y)`;

Is it safe? does the assignment do a copy from `y->b` to `x->b`? or just point `x->b` to `y->b`'s memory area?

I tested, seems no problem occurred.

Comment: Yes, it's safe. It is no different than without dynamic allocation. It's structure copying, which copies members. In fact, returning a fixed-length array from a function result often utilizes that language feature by burying the fixed-array inside a structure, then returning the structure as the function result. If `b` were *dynamic* this would be problematic, but as-is, there is no issues.

Comment: ASIDE: `memcpy(y->b, "aaaa", 4);` won't copy the null terminator at the end of the string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe you can do assignment like this(it is bit by bit copy)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct test
{
  int a;
  char b[20];
};

int main()
{
    struct test ob1,ob2;

    ob1.a=1;
    strcpy(ob1.b,"abc");

    ob2=ob1;

    printf("%c\n%s",ob2.a,ob2.b);

    return 0;
}
```

But See below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct test
{
  char *ptr;
};


int main()
{
    struct test ob1,ob2;

    ob1.ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    ob2.ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    if(ob1.ptr==NULL||ob2.ptr==NULL)
    {
        if(ob1.prt!=NULL)
            free(ob1.ptr);
        if(ob2.ptr!=NULL)
            free(ob2.ptr);

        exit(1);
    }    

    strcpy(ob1.ptr,"abc");
    ob2=ob1;
    strcpy(ob2.ptr,"def");

    printf("%s",ob1.ptr);

    free(ob1.ptr);
    free(ob2.ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints "def" and causes memory leak and frees same memory again so if you structure contains pointer you are responsible for that you can do something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct test
{
  char *ptr;
};

void testcopy(struct test* ob1,struct test* ob2)
{
   strcpy(ob1->ptr,ob2->ptr);
}

int main()
{
    struct test ob1,ob2;

    ob1.ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    ob2.ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    if(ob1.ptr==NULL||ob2.ptr==NULL)
    {
        if(ob1.prt!=NULL)
            free(ob1.ptr);
        if(ob2.ptr!=NULL)
            free(ob2.ptr);

        exit(1);
    }  

    strcpy(ob1.ptr,"abc");
    testcopy(&ob2,&ob1);
    strcpy(ob2.ptr,"def");

    printf("%s",ob1.ptr);
    printf("\n%s",ob2.ptr);

    free(ob1.ptr);
    free(ob2.ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also as @WhozCraig mentioned in comments it's safe and you are copying content of `*y` in `x` (so when `y` changes `x` won't).

not related to your question , but I want to say when you use `memcpy` if you want to copy complete string in to another one you should use `length of string + 1`(to copy `\0`). For example in your code `y->b` is not terminated.

also here this should be `struct test *y = malloc(sizeof(*y));` this:

`struct test *y = malloc(sizeof(y));`

to allocate memory for s a struct.(not a pointer)